# Published content is not shown in production

Tags: publishing

I am facing strange issue with Sitecore publishing. When I am publishing any item from the CM server, it's not reflected in production immediately; while I can see this item on the CD server and preview it as well. It is taking time (in hours) to refresh on production. Sometime when I reset the IIS, it works, but it is not possible for all the time.

Publish:end and publish:end:remote are:

```
<event name="publish:end">
 <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
 <sites hint="list">
  <site>website</site> 
  </sites>
  </handler>
  <handler type="our_app.Site.Events.ClearXO, our_dll" method="OnPublishEnd" /> 
  </event>
 <event name="publish:end:remote">
 <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
 <sites hint="list">
  <site>website</site> 
  </sites>
  </handler>
  </event>
```

Could someone help me out with what is being missed there?

Comment: Does your handler clears the cache?

Comment: I am sure about CM server, cache is being cleared there. could you help to check it on CD servers.

Comment: Does your eventQueue enable? Is the value of `processingInterval` set 00:00:02 and finally, have you set the scalability setting? And what Sitecore version are you using?

Comment: Yes EventQueue is enable. and I am using Sitecore 6.5.0 (rev. 121009)

Answer (score 7):

The reasons why the CD server is not clearing the cache is because the CD Server does not know what to do when receiving the events. So, you need to

**Scalability Settings**

The InstanceName is used (in this context) for comparison purposes, and for recording the instance that raised an event in the EventQueue, and the Publishing.PublishingInstance setting is used to ensure that all publishing operations are processed on a specific instance, e.g. if I have 3 CMs and set that to CM3 then CM3 will handle all publishing operations for the environment

On CM Servers:

```
<setting name="InstanceName">
   <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute>
</setting>

<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance">
   <patch:attribute name="value">CM1</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

On Publishing Server(1 of your CMs):

```
<setting name="InstanceName">
   <patch:attribute name="value">CM1</patch:attribute>
</setting>

<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance">
   <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

On CD Servers:

```
<setting name="InstanceName">
   <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute>
</setting>

<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance">
   <patch:attribute name="value">CM1</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

You also need to have eventQueue setting is enabled. In Sitecore v6.x to 7.2, it is found in the `web.config` and v7.5+ it is in the `Sitecore.config`

```
<setting name="EnableEventQueues" value="true">
```

and check if the ProcessingInterval of the EventQueue

```
<eventQueue>
  <!-- Time between checking the queue for newly queued events. If new events are found they will be raised. -->
  <processingInterval>00:00:02</processingInterval>
</eventQueue>
```

**Core Database**

Make sure that the events in the `eventqueue` table in core database of your CMs are also present in the `eventqueue` table of your CD. CM and the CDs should share the same core database, optionally through replication

**Sites**

Your sites should also be added to the `publish:end` and `publish:end:remote` events since by default, it contains only website. Note that, later on, when you have more sites you will require to update the config file. So, you can add a handler which reads your site definition and then clears the cache of the sites that you have.

**Indexes**

Make sure that there are no errors in your indexes. That is, Sitecore should be able to rebuild the indexes successfully else, the cache will not get cleared.

Comment: The reason why `ScalabilitySettings` must be enabled isn't quite accurate. What you described is more the job of the `eventQueue/processingInterval` setting that you already described. Also, the `InstanceName` is used (in this context) for comparison purposes, and for recording the instance that raised an event in the EventQueue, and the `Publishing.PublishingInstance` setting is used to ensure that all publishing operations are processed on a specific instance, e.g. if I have 3 CMs and set that to CM3 then CM3 will handle all publishing operations for the environment.

Comment: Also, while the information that you provided for the core database is mostly accurate, replication of the core database is not necessary, in this context. Replication is a good practice for failover, but it actually isn't needed to make the EventQueues work in a scaled environment Replication can optionally be used for security purposes, preventing the CD from connecting to the CM's core database. As such, what I think you were trying to say is simply that the "CM and the CDs should share the same core database, optionally through replication".

Comment: Sounds good. It looks like when you were writing your post some of the sections got a little mixed up. Happens to the best of us. Comment and tag me when fixed and I'll upvote it ;)

Comment: You forgot about the changes to the `core` database section. Also, the detail that you previously provided for `Scalability` settings should be added to the description for the `eventQueue/processingInterval`

Comment: Can you update it accordingly? I will be removing previous comments

Comment: Why are you removing your comments?

Comment: Because it was not related to the answer. It was more about how to structure the answer

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like the cache isn't getting cleared on publish. You'll want to add your site to the `publish:end` and `publish:end:remote` events.

```
<events>
      <event name="publish:end">
        <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
          <sites hint="list">
            <site>{site name}</site>
          </sites>
        </handler>
      </event><event name="publish:end:remote">
        <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
          <sites hint="list">
            <site>{site name}</site>
          </sites>
        </handler>
      </event>
    </events>
```

Comment: HI @Patrick my config values for publish:end And publish:end:remote are:

 <event name="publish:end">
- <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
- <sites hint="list">
  <site>website</site> 
  </sites>
  </handler>
  <handler type="Our_APP.Site.Events.ClearXO, Our_DLL" method="OnPublishEnd" /> 
  </event>
- <event name="publish:end:remote">
- <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
- <sites hint="list">
  <site>website</site> 
  </sites>
  </handler>
  </event>

Comment: For <site>website</site> the website value should be your CM name. That tells the event handler to look for that and fire off on the CD.

Comment: Looks like the publish end events are only wired up to your custom cache clearing. You'll want to add you site definition name to the sites list so that the needed Sitecore caches get cleared

Comment: +1 Great answer! @AmitSharma, it looks like you may also be using some sort of custom caching. If that is the case, try disabling your custom caching first and make sure that things work as expected. Once they do, re-enable your custom caching and troubleshoot more from there, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Patirck and Hishaam for your kind help, I've found the cause of the reported behavior. There was difference in databases on CM and CD servers, when we made our connection string same on CD servers as CM server, it's been resolved.

Thanks,
Amit